# PHP Workerman: Ошибка SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, ssl, tls

При запуске приложения на хостинге с SSL приложение выбрасывает несколько раз в минуту ошибку: SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request.

Приложение пишу на PHP в связке с JavaScript.

На стороне PHP использую Workerman + PHPSocketIO со следующим кодом:

```
<?php


use Workerman\Worker;
use Workerman\WebServer;
use Workerman\Autoloader;
use PHPSocketIO\SocketIO;

require_once __DIR__ '/vendor/autoload.php';

$context = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'local_cert' => 'ssl/cert.pem',
        'local_pk' => 'ssl/privkey.pem',
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_nam' => false
    )
);

$io = new SocketIO(1234, $context);

$io->on('connection', function($socket) {

    printf("Новое соединение%s", "\n");

    $socket->on('message', function($message) {
        $socket->broadcast->emit('message', $message);
    });
});

Worker::runAll();
```

На клиенте пишу следующий код:

```
<textarea id="messages"></textarea><br />
<input type="text" id="message" name="message" /><br />
<button id="send">Send</button>

<script type="text/javascript" defer>
    
    let messages = document.getElementById('messages');
    let message = document.getElementById('message');
    let send = document.getElementById('send');

    let socket = io.connect(':1234', {secure: true});

    socket.on('message', data => {
        messages.value += `${data}\r\n`
    })

    send.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        messages.value += `${message.value}\r\n`
        socket.emit('message', message.value)
        message.value = ''
    })

</script>
```

Собственно вопрос: почему возникает стек из ошибок:

SSL handshake error: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1407609C:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в занятых портах. Решение оказалось максимально простым:
Нужно было через netstat -tulpn получить список занятых портов и указать приложению свободный порт.